# Domain Definition in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a bounded complex-valued function $f(z)$ of a complex variable $z = x + iy$, where  $a < x < b$ ( $0 < a < b$) and $y \ge 1$.

Question: is the following a bounded domain:
$a < x < b$ and $y = c$ ($c = \text{constant} > 1$)

Some references define a bounded domain as an open connected finite set. Others add that a domain cannot be a line segment.

Comment: It will depend on your text's precise definition of "domain". In my experience, a domain in $\mathbb C$ is *usually* (at least) a set open in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Also, you probably don't mean a "finite" set. There are no open connected finite sets in $\mathbb C$ (except for $\varnothing$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean it's not open because y = c = constant?

Comment: Then a line segment cannot be a domain although the end values ("a" and "b" are not included).

Comment: What to change to "open" a domain around  "a" an "b" ?

Comment: So a line segment cannot be a domain, and the only domains are 2-dimensional shapes, or half strips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a *domain* in the context of complex analysis means an open, connected set. Not necessarily bounded (and certainly not finite).

Your set is not open, thus not a domain.

Comment: Then a <= x <= b and y = c  is a bounded domain